# Xamarin: How to remove an item in a specific row in Grid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dynamic, grid

I have a grid that I'm trying to remove an item in specific line. It's in a loop, then when it goes to the second line, it removes the item in second line and ALSO in the first line. How can I adjust to remove only the line that I want?

Note that what I'm trying to do is copy the first line to the second only solving the pow (b²), and in the third line I will copy the second line, but solve -4 * 5 (-4 * a).

This is the preview of what is happening.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uMB1.jpg) is my code to inflate these lines, to understand:
It enters first in the `if(fields == null)` because is pow, after that, goes to `else`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < qntLines; i++)
{
   string field = lines[i].Substring(0, lines[i].IndexOf('#'));
   string operation = lines[i].Substring(lines[i].IndexOf('#') + "#".Length);

   CreateResultLine(field, operation, i, listTexts);
}

private void CreateResultLine(string field, string operation, int i, List<string> listTexts)
{
            string[] fields = null;
            List<string> texts = new List<string>();
            string text = string.Empty;
            dynamic textResult;
            int count = new int();

            if (field.Contains(','))
                fields = field.Split(',', (char)StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            
            if (fields == null)
            {
                text = listTexts[int.Parse(field)];
                text = RemovePow(text);
                texts.Add(text);
                textResult = ExecuteOperation(texts, operation);
                
                gridFrame.Children.RemoveAt(int.Parse(field) + 1);
                gridFrame.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = textResult.ToString(), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, 
                    TextColor = Color.Blue, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, int.Parse(field) + 1, i);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in fields)
                {
                    string noPow = string.Empty;
                    noPow = RemovePow(listTexts[int.Parse(item)]);
                    texts.Add(noPow);
                    ++count;
                }
                textResult = ExecuteOperation(texts, operation);

                for (int i2 = int.Parse(fields[0]); i2 <= int.Parse(fields[1]);)
                {
                    gridFrame.Children.RemoveAt(int.Parse(fields[0]));
                    
                    ++i2;
                }

                gridFrame.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = textResult.ToString(), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, 
                    TextColor = Color.Blue, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, int.Parse(fields[0]) + 1, i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I haven't studied your code, but I'll make a general comment: rather than attempting to manipulate `gridFrame.Children`, why not simply set `someItem.IsVisible = false;`, where `someItem` is the grid cell you want to hide? Then to show a different result, have a different item that **starts out** with `IsVisible = false`, you update its Text, then set its `IsVisible=true`. To me, its easier to manipulate visibility of views, than to massage the Children of a layout.

Comment: Another idea: when you create each item, if you need to access it later,then "remember" it somehow. If a grid row is created in xaml, you can give it an `x:name` property. If a grid row is created in c#, then you can either make a list field with the ones you want to remember (so its easy to know the correct index), or you can add to a dictionary with a given key, to find it later by key string. Either way, you no longer have to *loop* through the children. You go directly to the item you care about.

Comment: Now for what's wrong with your code. I'm not going to read in detail, but one fact leaps out at me. When you do several `RemoveAt`s, as soon as you remove the first one, that **changes all the indices for later `RemoveAt`s**. One way to fix: **remove them "last first"**. A way to do that is to reverse your loop: **start at the highest index** and use decrement `--`. (Instead of starting at lowest index with increment.) An alternative solution is, as you find each item to remove, don't remove it yet. Put it in a "toRemove" list. Then when you've found them all, use **`Remove`** on each.

Comment: For your last comment, can you please show me some code example? I don't understand how can I make in the way that you're saying.

Comment: I've added an answer that shows a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example of working with the cells of a grid.

The concept is that you first create all the cells. Here, I use a `Label` in each grid cell. To make it easier to understand, I set each cell's text to the "CellNumber" that I assign to it. Once you understand what is going on, just put an empty string `""` as the initial value.

To make it easy to find the cells, there is a `Dictionary` containing them. `CellNumber(row, column)` gives the `key` to that dictionary, to find the corresponding cell.

`Calculate` button makes some changes to cells, so you can see how to do that.

I recommend NOT adding or removing cells (Children of Grid) once this is initialized. Instead, SHOW or HIDE a cell. Here, you do this by changing the `Text` of a `Label`. For other types of `View`s, you might change `View.IsVisible` to true or false.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ManipulateGridChildren.MainPage">

    <Grid x:Name="Formulas" BackgroundColor="#A0A0A0"
          RowSpacing="2" ColumnSpacing="2" Padding="2"
          ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*"
          RowDefinitions="40,40,40,Auto">
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Text="Calc" Command="{Binding CalcCommand}" />
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ManipulateGridChildren
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        const int NRows = 3;
        static int NColumns = 8;
        const int MaxColumns = 100;

        private Dictionary<int, Label> cells = new Dictionary<int, Label>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddCells();
            CalcCommand = new Command(Calculate);
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        public Command CalcCommand { get; set; }

        private void Calculate()
        {
            SetCellText(0, 0, "A");
            SetCellText(0, 2, "B");
            SetCellText(1, 0, "C");
            SetCellText(2, 3, "D");
            SetCellBackground(2, 3, Color.Pink)
        }

        private void SetCellText(int row, int column, string text)
        {
            cells[CellNumber(row, column)].Text = text;
        }

        private void SetCellBackground(int row, int column, Color color)
        {
            cells[CellNumber(row, column)].BackgroundColor = color;
        }

        private void AddCells()
        {
            // Grid rows and columns are numbered from "0".
            for (int row = 0; row < NRows; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < NColumns; column++) {
                    var cell = AddCell(row, column);
                    cells[CellNumber(row, column)] = cell;
                }
            }

            // Add "frames" around some rows.
            // AFTER adding the cells, so drawn on top.
            AddFrame(0, 1, 0, NColumns);
            AddFrame(1, 2, 0, NColumns);
        }

        private Label AddCell(int row, int column)
        {
            var cell = new Label();
            // For debugging - show where each cell is.
            // Once you understand, change this to an empty string.
            cell.Text = $"{CellNumber(row, column)}";
            cell.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            cell.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            cell.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            Formulas.Children.Add(cell, column, row);
            return cell;
        }

        // Assign unique number to each cell.
        private int CellNumber(int row, int column)
        {
            return row * MaxColumns + column;
        }

        private void AddFrame(int row, int rowSpan, int column, int columnSpan)
        {
            var rect = new Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Rectangle {
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Black),
                StrokeThickness = 2
            };

            Formulas.Children.Add(rect, column, column + columnSpan, row, row + rowSpan);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed the idea to create a List of Grid and then just show if it's visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

A bit confused of what you're trying to achieve, but here's a sugestion.

I recommend going for a MVVM pattern. Manipulating UI in code is not the best idea.

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
   <local: MainViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>

  <ListView ItemSource={Binding ListOfItems}>
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
             <Label Text={Binding .}/>
          <ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

public ObservableCollection<string> ListOfItems {get;set;} = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public void DeleteAnItem(string s)
{
  ListOfItems.Remove(s);
}

public void AddItem(string s)
{
 ListOfItems.Add(s);
}

public void RemoveAtIndex(int i)
{
  ListOfItems.RemoveAt(i);
}

#region TheRestOfPropertyChanged
...
#endregion
}
```

Every change you do to the list will be visibile in your UI.